# Highlight Sentence if it has any Revision

Tags: vba, ms-word

This macro will highlight all of the revisions in the document, whether they are deletions or insertions. It will also highlight the entire sentence that contains the revision. The sentence will start with a capital letter and end with a period, colon, question mark, exclamation point, comma, or semicolon.

```
Public Sub Highlight_trackchange()

Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim rev As Word.Revision

Set doc = Word.ActiveDocument

For Each rev In doc.Revisions

If rev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Or rev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then

Set rng = rev.Range

Do While rng.Start < rng.End


If rng.Start.Text.IsLetter Then

Do While rng.End.Character.IsNotOneOf(vbCrLf, vbQuestion, vbExclamation, vbPeriod, vbColon, vbSemicolon, vbComma)

rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

rng.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1

Loop

End If

rng.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1

Loop

End If

Next rev

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using the display of tracked changes built into Word?

Comment: i want to highlight the entire segment if it has any change because the source document we are making revision is translated to other languages. and the translations are done on segment basis. so if i can isolate only segments with revisions it will helps translators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```vb
Sub Highlight_Sentence_if_it_has_any_Revision()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rev As Revision, rng As Word.Range, sentence As Word.Range, ur As Word.UndoRecord
    
    Set doc = Word.ActiveDocument: Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Highlight_Sentence_if_it_has_any_Revision"
    
    For Each rev In doc.Revisions
    
        If rev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Or rev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
        
            For Each sentence In rev.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Sentences
                If VBA.InStr(sentence.Text, rev.Range.Text) And sentence.Start <= rev.Range.Start And sentence.End >= rev.Range.End Then
                    sentence.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
            Next sentence
        
        End If
    
    Next rev

    ur.EndCustomRecord
    
End Sub
```